# Capture SQL/Developer Script Output in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, dbms-output

In SQL/Developer, when I execute a statement I get a Script Output message that reads something like `7 Records Merged`

Here's my relevant PL/SQL Code:

`v_sql_loader := 'merge into foobar  b using  foobiz i on (b.foobar_id = i.foobiz_id)  when not matched then insert (foobar_id) values (foobiz_id)';`

`execute immediate v_sql_loader;`

How can I capture `7 records Merged` in PL/SQL?

I'm writing `dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM)` but that only returns
`ORA-0000: normal, successful completion`

What Oracle/PLSQL object can I use to replicate SQL/Developer Script Output messages?

Desired Results: PLSQL Statement, preferably `dbms_output.put_line()`;that indicates `7 Records Merged.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`:

```
BEGIN
   ...
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_loader;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Merged: ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
/
```